# CONCAT two newly created date and time fields in the same query

Tags: sql, date, time, google-bigquery, concatenation

I have parsed two separate date and time fields from STRINGS to DATES and TIME (see below)

```
SELECT 
safe.parse_date('%Y%m%d',Arrival_Date) eventdate,
safe.parse_time("%H:%M",Arrival_Time) eventtime
 FROM 
table
```

Within the same query I now want to CONCAT them into one column as a DATETIME field. I can't figure it out. CAST(CONCAT doesn't work as both fields need to safe.parsed due to errors and nulls in the original columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try below query:

```sql
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT '20221011' Arrival_Date, '10:14' Arrival_Time
)
SELECT safe.parse_date('%Y%m%d',Arrival_Date) eventdate,
       safe.parse_time("%H:%M",Arrival_Time) eventtime,
       safe.parse_datetime("%Y%m%d%H:%M", Arrival_Date || Arrival_Time) eventdatetime,
  FROM `table`;
```

If **Arrival_Time** has an emptry string or `null`, you can try below as well.

```sql
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT '20221011' Arrival_Date, '10:14' Arrival_Time UNION ALL 
  SELECT '20221012' Arrival_Date, '' Arrival_Time UNION ALL
  SELECT '20221013' Arrival_Date, NULL Arrival_Time
)
SELECT safe.parse_datetime(
         "%Y%m%d%H:%M",
         Arrival_Date || IFNULL(NULLIF(TRIM(Arrival_Time), ''), '00:00')
       ) AS eventdatetime,
  FROM `table`;

+---------------------+
|    eventdatetime    |
+---------------------+
| 2022-10-11T10:14:00 |
| 2022-10-12T00:00:00 |
| 2022-10-13T00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you - this has worked - although I wasn't sure about this part as it only returned a specific row, whereas I want all rows:

WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT '20221011' Arrival_Date, '10:14' Arrival_Time
)

When I remove that part, I get the desired result.

Comment: and you can add additional null handling if you want like below :
**safe.parse_datetime("%Y%m%d%H:%M", Arrival_Date || IFNULL(Arrival_Time, '00:00'))**

Comment: So the IFNULL doesn't always work when the time field is empty/blank, i.e. .no time entry, but a does have a date entry. It just returns nothing at all, even if the row has a date.Bit confused. Happy to provide an example.

Comment: @Raven52, if **Arrival_Time** can have an emptry string as well as **null**, you can handle both at the same time. Kindly check the updated answer.